# setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds doesn't work with BiometricPrompt

Tags: android, androidx, android-biometric-prompt

I am implemented biometric authentication with BiometricPrompt (androidx). It works  well but I can use key only one time. If I trying to use it second time immedatelly  after first time - I get an exception UserNotAuthenticatedException. For key creation I am using this code:

```
KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
    .build()
```

I also trying to add `.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(10)` to resolve my problem. But it work only after unlock device using power button. And doesn't work BiometricPrompt request. It looks like a bug. Is the solution exists?